# Extracting data from plain text string

Tags: c#, regex, string, string-matching

I am trying to process a report from a system which gives me the following code

```
000=[GEN] OK {Q=1 M=1 B=002 I=3e5e65656-e5dd-45678-b785-a05656569e}
```

I need to extract the values between the curly brackets {} and save them in to variables. I assume I will need to do this using regex or similar? I've really no idea where to start!! I'm using c# asp.net 4.

I need the following variables

```
param1 = 000
param2 = GEN
param3 = OK
param4 = 1 //Q
param5 = 1 //M
param6 = 002 //B
param7 = 3e5e65656-e5dd-45678-b785-a05656569e //I
```

I will name the params based on what they actually mean. Can anyone please help me here? I have tried to split based on spaces, but I get the other garbage with it!

Thanks for any pointers/help!

Comment: split on the "="? Will it always be in this format?

Comment: Y do you want to capture `GEN`,`OK` when they would always be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a regular expression for this type of work.

```
var objRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^(\d+)=\[([A-Z]+)\] ([A-Z]+) \{Q=(\d+) M=(\d+) B=(\d+) I=([a-z0-9\-]+)\}$");
var objMatch = objRegex.Match("000=[GEN] OK {Q=1 M=1 B=002 I=3e5e65656-e5dd-45678-b785-a05656569e}");
if (objMatch.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(objMatch.Groups[1].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(objMatch.Groups[2].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(objMatch.Groups[3].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(objMatch.Groups[4].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(objMatch.Groups[5].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(objMatch.Groups[6].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(objMatch.Groups[7].ToString());
}
```

I've just tested this out and it works well for me.

Answer (score 3):

If the format is pretty constant, you can use .NET string processing methods to pull out the values, something along the lines of

```
string line = 
    "000=[GEN] OK {Q=1 M=1 B=002 I=3e5e65656-e5dd-45678-b785-a05656569e}";

int start = line.IndexOf('{');
int end = line.IndexOf('}');
string variablePart = line.Substring(start + 1, end - start);
string[] variables = variablePart.Split(' ');
foreach (string variable in variables)
{
    string[] parts = variable.Split('=');
    // parts[0] holds the variable name, parts[1] holds the value
}
```

Wrote this off the top of my head, so there may be an off-by-one error somewhere.  Also, it would be advisable to add error checking e.g. to make sure the input string has both a { and a }.

Comment: although this is an alternative to `regex` but still you are making it way to complex..`regex` would do it in a better way without cluttering  the code...also this would result into an array which the op doesn't want..he wants to store it in individual variables..non-regex solution is not recommended here..

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: Maybe.  It really depends on the requirements.  RegEx is often *slower*.  Dropping my code and hal.stephenk's code into a simple console app and running each 1,000,000 times (only repeating `objRegex.Match`, not the `new RegularExpression`) shows 1.052 seconds for my code and 6.663 seconds for his code.  Sometimes, that performance matters.  Sometimes it does not.  RegEx is a general pattern matching solution.  It will almost never be as fast to execute as purpose-written code, though it can be faster to write.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression.

Quick and dirty attempt:

```
(?<ID1>[0-9]*)=\[(?<GEN>[a-zA-Z]*)\] OK {Q=(?<Q>[0-9]*) M=(?<M>[0-9]*) B=(?<B>[0-9]*) I=(?<I>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)}
```

This will generate named groups called `ID1`, `GEN`, `Q`, `M`, `B` and `I`.

Check out the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) for details on using Regular Expressions in C#.

You can use [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/) for quick C# regex testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Split`

```
string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] {"=[", "] ", " {Q=", " M=", " B=", " I=", "}"},
                         StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution breaks up your report code into segments and stores the desired values into an array.

The regular expression matches one report code segment at a time and stores the appropriate values in the "Parsed Report Code Array".

As your example implied, the first two code segments are treated differently than the ones after that. I made the assumption that it is always the first two segments that are processed differently.

```
private static string[] ParseReportCode(string reportCode) {
    const int FIRST_VALUE_ONLY_SEGMENT = 3;
    const int GRP_SEGMENT_NAME = 1;
    const int GRP_SEGMENT_VALUE = 2;
    Regex reportCodeSegmentPattern = new Regex(@"\s*([^\}\{=\s]+)(?:=\[?([^\s\]\}]+)\]?)?");
    Match matchReportCodeSegment = reportCodeSegmentPattern.Match(reportCode);

    List<string> parsedCodeSegmentElements = new List<string>();
    int segmentCount = 0;
    while (matchReportCodeSegment.Success) {
        if (++segmentCount < FIRST_VALUE_ONLY_SEGMENT) {
            string segmentName = matchReportCodeSegment.Groups[GRP_SEGMENT_NAME].Value;
            parsedCodeSegmentElements.Add(segmentName);
        }
        string segmentValue = matchReportCodeSegment.Groups[GRP_SEGMENT_VALUE].Value;
        if (segmentValue.Length > 0) parsedCodeSegmentElements.Add(segmentValue);
        matchReportCodeSegment = matchReportCodeSegment.NextMatch();
    }
    return parsedCodeSegmentElements.ToArray();
}
```